# admin area in sub directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a system that has both a front end and an administration area.

currently i am giving the admin area a subdomain.

what i'd like to do it have it as a sub directory, e.g http://domain.com/admin

but the admin area is set up to be placed in root.

can i put something in my .htaccess to make the sub directory "/admin" think its the root?

Comment: If the administration area thinks that it lives at the root of the domain, any navigation it generates will be indistinguishable from normal site requests (since it won't be pointed at `/admin/`), so there's really no workable solution based on that. In essence, convincing the code it's at the root basically just adds to the problem, because the rewriting only works one way. What requires the administration area to think that it lives at the site root?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to subdomains, you could place the admin interface under admin.domain.com, and use domain.com/admin as a redirect.

It's horrid, but so the software's requirement on placement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. First, neither 'DocumentRoot' nor 'Alias' can occur in .htaccess. 
But anyway, if you think about it, by the time it reads your .htaccess it's interpreted the paths, so it's too late to change them.

I'm not sure if you might be able to do what you want with rewriting.